# php mysql select from columns from 2 tables Join

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables.
visitors_details, with id,scanner_id,time columns
and visitors_info with scanner_id, name,surname columns

I want to get back 
id,name,surname,time in a table

i have written this but is not working

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT visitors_details.id AS id, 
visitors_info.name AS name, visitors_info.surname AS surname, visitors_details.time 
AS time FROM visitors_details AS d LEFT JOIN visitors_info AS i ON 
d.scanner_id=i.scanner_id ");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>id</th>
<th>name</th>
<th>surname</th>
<th>Time</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
 echo "<tr>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>"; 
 echo "<td>" . $row['surname'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['time'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
   echo "</table>";
```

any ideas??

Comment: What about it is not working? Is your query itself not returning what you want, or are you having trouble with your php code?

Comment: Try changing the columns in the select to the table aliases ie: `SELECT d.id AS id, 
i.name AS name, i.surname AS surname, d.time 
AS time`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its better to enable some debugging for your code like this:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$sql = "
SELECT d.id AS id, i.name AS name, i.surname AS surname, d.time  AS time 
  FROM visitors_details AS d 
  LEFT JOIN visitors_info AS i ON d.scanner_id=i.scanner_id
";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

?>
```

Comment: thanks... i just changed the aliases in the first select as you mentioned and the results appear

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT d.id , i.name , i.surname , d.time 
                       FROM visitors_details AS d LEFT JOIN visitors_info AS i 
                        ON d.scanner_id=i.scanner_id ");
```

Comment: thanks !! i just changed the aliases in the first select as you mentioned and the results appear now

Comment: nice that i could help you !

Answer (score 0):

Add this to catch errors. saves a lot of time:

```
if(!$result) {
    echo mysql_error();
}
```